# Increasing font and line space in compiling document

Tags: winedt

I use WinEdt for compiling my latex code, unfortunately the default font size in WinEdt window is too small and this put lot of strain on eyes while correcting code in it. The line spacing need also to be increase for more visibility. How I can do it?

Comment: You mean the source is too small etc.? Or do you mean the font and line spacing in the compiled document (e.g. the PDF)?

Comment: I mean font in source code is too small.

Comment: In WinEdt open "Options", select "Preferences" and in it open "Change Font". There select font and it size according to your wishes.

Comment: In preferences you can not increase font beyond 12, Max font limit given there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Zarko suggests in the above comment, you can go for a simple way.

In the "Options" menu, select "Preferences" and then the "Font" tab. By clicking on the "Change Font" button you have the chance of selecting a different font, a different size, etc.

[image]

If you want more control over the font used in documents, download and install the add-on [DocZoom](http://www.winedt.org/macros/winedt/DocZoom.html).

Through the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> you can increase or reduce, respectively, the size of the font used in documents. The range of available sizes is 8<->20.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is my mistake that I did not explored option->preferences further.